# Join two query in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, postgresql

I want to join two querys into one query.

What retrieved in the first query is a tables with column of `resourceindex` that sorts ascending:

```
String loadRates = "SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE userindex="
            + uindex
            + " ORDER BY rank  DESC";
```

And in the second query, what should retrieved is rows of `resourceindexes`:

```
String loadResources = "SELECT * FROM resourceinfo WHERE resourceindex = "
                    + rs.getInt("resourceindex");
```

How I can I combine these into a single query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ri.* FROM resourceinfo ri, ratings r
WHERE ri.resourceindex = r.resourceindex AND r.userindex = ?
ORDER BY r.rank DESC
```